# Capture a group in a multi-line string with multiple matches using regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to capture the String '1611650547*42' in the multiple line String bellow.

```
myString = "'/absfucate/wait.do;cohrAwdSessID=jbreW9yA8R0xh9b?
obfuscateId=jbreW9yA8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tObfuscate=null&
tSession_1DS=null&obsfuscate3=DeptNLI8261138&
dispatchMethod=obfuscate'+ '&poll= 
8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tSession=null'"
```

I'm using the the code bellow. And it captures two groups. When

```
/checksum=(?<checksum>\d*\*\d*)/m.match(myString)['checksum']
```

The capturing group `checksum` works for a string with one match, but when using multiple matches are found it throws the following error

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: I think the '/m' marker would solve the problem. Using the single line string 'obfuscateId=jbreW9yA8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tObfuscate=null' it works fine.

Comment: I've run your code (with `/` at the beginning) and it returned `"1611650547*42"`

Comment: Actually the code has the '/' at the beginning.

Comment: So, with your data it returned what you expected (for me at least)

Comment: You're right. The string is actually a complex HTML page. I'm checking how to reproduce the problem with a shorter String.

Comment: I fixed the string and now the error can be reproduced I added the string "8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tSession=null" to the end of it.

Comment: Still seems to work for me...

Comment: Hi @UriAgassi, Have you tried using the string witch two matching groups. I found out that the problem was not only a string with multiple lines, but the problem occurs when you have more than one match. Adding another 'checksum=1611650547*42' to the String the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Copying the code as it is now in your post - works fine (returns the first match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be 100% sure about your input and the criteria revolving around the `*`. How about trying something a bit more specific (Ruby 2):

```
if myString =~ /(?m)checksum=\K\d*\*\d*/
    checksum = $&
```

**What does the regex mean?**

- Use these options for the whole regular expression `(?m)`

  - &Dot matches line breaks `m`
- Match the character string “checksum=” literally (case sensitive) `checksum=`
- Keep the text matched so far out of the overall regex match `\K`
- Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) `\d*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the character “*” literally `\*`
- Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) `\d*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`

Comment: The question string didn't reproduce the problem. I fixed the string and now the error raises with your solution to (although its far more elegant)

Comment: It worked zx81. Could you please detail your regular expression (specially '(?m)' and '\K'.

Comment: @RafaelBorja Glad it works, thank you for letting me know. Added explanation of the regex. `(?m)` means that `^` matches on each new line, since we are not using `^` we don't need that. `\K` is great, it tells the engine that whatever was matched up to that point, don't include it in the reported match.

Comment: @RafaelBorja FYI several tools generate automatic explanations, such as RegexBuddy, regex101 and [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?)

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = "'/absfucate/wait.do;cohrAwdSessID=jbreW9yA8R0xh9b?
obfuscateId=jbreW9yA8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tObfuscate=null&
tSession_1DS=null&obsfuscate3=DeptNLI8261138&
dispatchMethod=obfuscate'+ '&poll= 
8R0xh9b&checksum=1611650547*42&tSession=null'"

myString.scan(/checksum=[^&]+/) # => ["checksum=1611650547*42", "checksum=1611650547*42"]
```

Since your string contains two, and you don't say which one you want, pick one or the other, then continue processing:

```
myString.scan(/checksum=[^&]+/).first.split('=').last # => "1611650547*42"
```

Basically `/checksum=[^&]+/` means: Find `"checksum="` then the text following it until the next `&`. Once I have those strings it's easy to split them on `=`.

Regex aren't magic bullets, and will make your life more and more miserable the longer and more complex they become, so use them carefully and sparingly. Rather than try to process the entire line in one pattern, `scan` lets me use a small pattern to locate only what I want, and it handles the task of looping through the entire string.

If I was only after one of the occurrences, I'd use a pattern and `match`. These are equivalent to what you were after, only they're more succinct:

```
myString.match(/checksum=(?<checksum>[^&]+)/m)[:checksum] # => "1611650547*42"
myString.match(/checksum=(?<checksum>[\d*]+)/m)[:checksum] # => "1611650547*42"
```

For readability I'd use the pattern as the parameter for `match`, rather than chain `match` to the `m` flag.